# Sending contents to one file to another?

Tags: php, localhost, httprequest

I'm learning HTTP requests, response, client/server aspects of PHP.
I have a directory and a php -S localhost in socket 8080 running in the directory, in it there's:

1. index.php
2. send.php

I want send.php to send index.php lets say, a string or something simple. How would I go about this?

Comment: You could use `curl`. http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: I read about most of it but I still don't quite get it. Like the concept? the conception? It just isn't clicking with me. How would code it?